# Linux - How to upload code to a dedicated freescale chip NIC on my motherboard?

Tags: c, linux, driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have bought a Gigabyte g1.guerilla motherboard and the NIC is a dedicated freescale chip on the motherboard. It is connected to the PCI bus.

I am running Linux and unfortunately there is no driver for it. I am working to write one, however I am hitting a basic problem: How to communicate and upload code to its dedicated CPU-RAM?

Much help appreciated.

I am running on ubuntu and the chip is a mpc8308vmagd PowerQuicc II pro

Comment: Upload code? Generally, you create a [binary blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_blob) and load it with your driver.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, thanks for the keyword hint. I am looking for some code/link/explanation on how to do it. Especially details as to how to find base address of the device and also how to find the address of the registers. The information is very thin on that chip.

Comment: Take a look with `lspci -v`. As for going further, especially with-out cooperation from Gigabyte, I expect it's going to be hard. You certainly aren't going to find a detailed guide.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of trying to probe the chip via the PCI bridge. I think there is a cli tool on linux to send byte stream to a device? Something like  pci_bridge [device_id] [chip cpu addr] [assembly opcode for the cpu]. The part I have a hard time wrapping my head around is that I feel like I need to do <Host CPU> -> <PCI device> ??-> <Chip CPU>. I'm a bit ignorant on that topic but it seems like normally in a driver you can access the onboard chip directly with opcodes where in that code it might need to be routed on the chip internal bus?

Comment: *"How to ... upload code"*  -- Uh, that would be download, as the system hierarchy puts the peripheral below the host.  There is a Linux mechanism for a driver to request a firmware file from a userspace daemon, that daemon will read the file and transfer it to the driver.  How to write this FW to the device is typically very device specific.  Why are you guessing? You need to study **[the reference manual for the device](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MPC8308RM.pdf)**

Comment: *"I was thinking of writing a very lightweight super-simple OS."* -- Better think again.  If you're not going to use the MPC8308 as a NPU, you should save yourself the effort, and just install an ordinary NIC.  Otherwise you need a protocol stack and should install an embedded Linux kernel in the MPC8308 to service the two(?) Ethernet ports.

Comment: Here's a review of [the discrete PCIe adapter version of that Bigfoot NPU](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3716/bigfoot-networks-announces-3rd-gen-killer-nic-killer-2100)  You would need access to the serial console of the NPU to facilitate any FW development.  Unfortunately the discrete PCIe adapter is more likely than the mobo to have an exposed connector (e.g. 4-pin TTL port). J9 in [this photo](http://extreme.pcgameshardware.de/attachments/268252d1284320718-lesertest-bigfoot-networks-killer-2100-wincenty-bild5490.jpg) (top right) could be for a serial console.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about your specific motherboard or the processor, but are you totally sure you need to upload any code to the processor?

Usually, if a peripheral needs any code (firmware), it's already present on a ROM or a flash chip and you only need to touch it if you specifically want to write your own firmware for it. AFAIK the way it usually works is that the peripheral exposes a set of registers on the PCI bus and you interact with it by poking the registers (usually with MMIO). That is, you don't write code for the peripheral, but you write a kernel driver that pokes the registers (ie. the API for the peripheral) when it wants the device to do something.

Now, in general the register descriptions aren't often freely available, which can make writing drivers really hard.

If you really want/need to write your own firmware for the thing, it probably depends on where the code is stored. If it sits in ROM or in an inaccessible flash, you'll probably need to do some soldering. If the firmware is updatable, I'd probably try to reverse-engineer the software they provide for updating the firmware, if one is available. (Unless it allows uploading arbitrary files already, of course)

Comment: It really is a system on a chip so you have a PowerPC processor, a DDR2 dedicated RAM, more+. If interested look at figure 1 in the 1. Overview : http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/MPC8308EC.pdf?pspll=1&Parent_nodeId=1256917005044720619508&Parent_pageType=product

It shows the layout of the chip. Not sure either but it doesn't look like there is ROM on the device. I was thinking of writing a very lightweight super-simple OS.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean that it would be on the device itself, but on the motherboard, connected to the device. After all, it must load it's code from somewhere, be it a ROM chip or a flash chip. Again, I'm totally not sure about it, but if I had to bet, I'd say the SoC is already programmed for you, with the code (firmware) sitting on a separate chip, and you just need to interact with the software already running on the dedicated CPU. That is, poke the device address space through PCI. But again, this is just how it usually works, I could be totally wrong in relation to this specific case.

Comment: Linux requires a firmware download to some peripherals, especially 802.11 adapters and TV tuners.  The directory `/lib/firmware` is used to store these files.  *"I don't know anything about..."* -- Yet you feel compelled to answer?

Comment: @sawdust I am well aware of that, many modern GPUs also need to have firmware loaded during runtime. However, I've never heard of an ethernet NIC needing it. That doesn't mean they don't exist, of course, but I tried to be quite clear on that point. Pardon me, but I've managed to help people quite often without knowing the specifics of their problem. In this case, it sounded like the device needing external firmware was a baseless assumption by the OP. Based on the device not having a Linux driver yet, I assume there are only a handful of people that do know anything about the device, (cont'd)

Comment: namely the people who designed the motherboard/NIC. I'm doubtful that they simultaneously follow stackoverflow, see this question, and are able to disclose anything. Would you rather no-one try to help OP because they don't have any definite information? And yes, there's a reference manual for the SoC; No, I can't quite see how it helps with this question, since you need to know how the chip is connected, too - the chip doesn't seem to have integrated memory. Really, I just made him a suggestion to double-check his assumptions, which might save him lots of time down the wrong road - or not.

Comment: If you think giving suggestions is the worst thing ever, so be it. (You know why IT support usually asks to double-check that all cables are connected? It's so simple that everyone checks that before calling in, right? Nope, simple things like that are really common. It really doesn't hurt to check the simplest things first - it might save a *lot* of time trying to figure out irrelevant hard stuff)

Comment: The typical NIC is just a connector, a PHY, an EMAC and a bus interface,.  But the OP's mobo doesn't have an ordinary NIC.  This Gigabyte mobo has a network subsystem with its own processor, and refers to the installed MPC8308 as a network processor, or NPU.  So like the GPU you mention or 802.11 USB adapters, it could require a FW download.  So instead of posting a hasty "answer" based on assumptions, why not ask the OP some questions first for clarification in a comment?  Like you yourself wrote, ask questions for clarification.